# flashing row in telerik GridView

Tags: wpf, gridview

I am newbie with telerik controls, and I am doing a app with a GridView, I would like to make some rows blink or flash.

I have find a Style that do it through StyleSelector, but when I tried to use styleSelectors to change row background color the scroll didn't work right.

Does anybody knows if there is an easy way?
Hope somebody can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So the solution to this would be to apply a row style selector and target it at the TargetType of a telerik:GridViewRow..

```
<Behaviours:FlashingRowStyleSelector x:Key="resultsGridStyle">
        <Behaviours:FlashingRowStyleSelector.SucceededStyle>
            <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                          Duration="0:0:0.2"  From="White" To="Red" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>

        </Behaviours:FlashingRowStyleSelector.SucceededStyle>
```

And then in your   have this property set

RowStyleSelector="{StaticResource resultsGridStyle}"

To then control this - you'd have to write a class which inherits from StyleSelector which decides which style to choose depending on the value from any of the rows items in the populated grid. So something like this should do the trick

```
public class FlashingRowStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the succeeded style.
    /// </summary>
    public Style SucceededStyle { get; set; }

/// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the succeeded style.
    /// </summary>
    public Style NormalStyle{ get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// The select style.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">
    /// The item.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="container">
    /// The container.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="Style"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var info = item as RowObject
        if (info != null)
        {
            if (info.SomeProperty == "1")
            {
                return this.SucceededStyle;
            }


        }

        return this.NormalStyle;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Basically all this is doing is to set the style based on a property of 1 being set...
So if one of the rows in your grid fulfils this condition then it will animate for the required duration from white to red.

Comment: Check out repeatbehavior to control how many times the animation triggers.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.repeatbehavior.aspx

Comment: And depending on which version of the telerik control you use (and the grid performance you require) you can play with turning off an on EnableRowVirtualisation which will cause the grid to not regenerate the row container each time you scroll and therefore not firing PropertyChanged and hence not triggering the animation again.